# Linux command to repeat a string n times

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell, text-manipulation

Is there any built-in Linux command that allows to output a string that is n times an input string??

Comment: By "built-in linux command" I assume you mean shell command, and since you don't mention which shell you're using, I assume it's bash. You can check this by typing "echo $SHELL" at the command line and you should get something similar to "/bin/bash" back. If you don't, you should edit your answer to specify what it does show. Cheers :)

Comment: I tagged the question with "bash". I thought that would've been enough.

Comment: Related on [SO]: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3211891/2157640

Answer (score 131, accepted):

```
adrian@Fourier:~$ printf 'HelloWorld\n%.0s' {1..5}
HelloWorld
HelloWorld
HelloWorld
HelloWorld
HelloWorld
adrian@Fourier:~$
```

Comment: Could you explain how this works? I understand the printf command since it's the same as the one in C/C++. But I dont understand how the {1..5} is expanded and how that works in conjunction with the "%.0s" part.

Comment: It's a bit of a hack :) Try running "printf 'HelloWorld %d\n' 1 2 3 4 5" and it'll probably click for you. The %.0s flag is meant to do nothing, just be there to pick up arguments. Then, if bash gets more arguments than it has format specifiers, it will simply print out multiple copies, grabbing as many as it needs. So you get the effect. The output of "printf 'HelloWorld %d%d\n' 1 2 3 4 5 6" probably makes it even clearer. Hope this helps!

Comment: I see. It's the particular behavior of printf what allows the repetition

Comment: (I should note that, from a purely theoretical standpoint, this is probably the fastest solution since it uses a single shell primitive -- not any external processes. In reality though, let's face it, performance of bash scripts doesn't really matter :)

Comment: NB: The expansion of {x..y} is not specific to printf.  This is a bash syntax that expands to a sequence of numbers x, x+1, ..., y.  For example, try "echo {1..10}".  This is in the "Brace Expansion" section of the bash man page (and is called a "sequence expression").

Comment: What *is* specific to `printf` is that it will repeatedly apply excess arguments to the format string, "looping" for free. By "excess", I mean that there are more arguments than `%` placeholders.

Comment: Uggh. Why `bash` (POSIX?) chose to do this is totally beyond me. I've been bitten by this when messing with my GRUB2 configuration.

Comment: This doesn't work if we want to repeat 0 time.

Comment: I love this but it doesn't work if the string to be repeated is exactly `-`, which just so happens to be what I want (making a little banner with hyphens). Oh well. I'll upgrade the two banner types from `---`/`===` to `===`/`###`. Oh, another wrinkle, best to quote shellcheck: `Bash doesn't support variables in brace range expansions.`

Comment: @StevenLu this will work for you: `printf -- '-%.0s' {1..5}` and for variable length: `printf -- '-%.0s' $(seq 1 $length)`, but the command substitution is relatively expensive, performance wise ;).

Comment: Nice! good trick there thanks. Haha I can't believe I didn't think of using positional arguments

Comment: Doesn't work if you use a variable for the range, e.g. `printf -- 'HelloWorld\n%.0s' {1..${num_lines}}`

Answer (score 112):

Here's an old-fashioned way that's pretty portable:

```
yes "HelloWorld" | head -n 10
```

This is a more conventional version of **Adrian Petrescu's** answer using brace expansion:

```
for i in {1..5}
do
    echo "HelloWorld"
done
```

That's equivalent to:

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 5
```

This is a little more concise and dynamic version of **pike's** answer:

```
printf -v spaces '%*s' 10 ''; printf '%s\n' ${spaces// /ten}
```

Comment: How do you get rid of the new lines when using the yes command?

Comment: One way is to pipe it through `sed -n 'H;${x;s/\n//gp}'` or `sed -n ':t;${s/\n//gp};N;bt'` another is to do `echo $(yes "HelloWorld" | head -n 10)` which adds a space between each copy of the string. Yet another way is to pipe it through `tr -d '\n'` which also eliminates the final newline.

Comment: It's like Haskell in a bash shell: Hashell?

Comment: The yes solution is pretty neat

Comment: The `yes` solution was exactly what I needed, since I wanted to duplicate a command (whose output fluctuates). Thus: `yes "$(my-command)" | head -n 2`

Comment: @arnsholt: I'm not sure what you mean by fluctuate. The command substitution only gets run once and `yes` outputs the same thing (the single output of the command substitution) multiple times. For example, compare `yes "$(date +%N; sleep 1)" | head -n 4` and `for i in {1..4}; do date +%N; sleep 1; done`

Comment: The output is based on a random sampling, so running the command twice yields somewhat different results each time. I actually wanted the exact same string twice (because the output was going into a script that generates a table, and that particular row was supposed to be the same number twice [where other rows varied, obviously]).

Comment: @arnsholt: OK, I would use a `for` loop instead of spawning an external executable (`yes`). Or capture it once and output it twice like: `out=$(my-command); printf '%s\n' "$out" "$out"` (`printf` will apply excess arguments sequentially) or other similar techniques.

Answer (score 29):

You can use a trick. Echoing an empty variable does not print anything. So you can write:

```
echo word$wojek{1..100}
```

If `$wojek1 $wojek2` ... `$wojek100` are non-existing variables you will get your word repeated 100 times without anything else.

Comment: It's an ugly ugly hack, and yet I can't help but love it and use it.

Comment: Love it! Maybe using `$_` instead of `$wojek` makes the intent clearer.

Comment: Great trick. For those who care a little bit more about bash scripts' correctness this should be:
`set +u; echo word$wojek{1..100}; set -u`
assuming `set -eu` is set above.

Comment: If you want to use this technique to place the repeated string in a variable: `printf -v varname '%s' word$_{1..10}`. You can include any formatting you like. One difference is that if you use `'%s '` (ends in a space) there will be a trailing space which isn't present in the `echo` technique. You can also do `varname=$(echo word$_{1..10})`.

Comment: Try `_5=MIDPOINT` before you do `echo word$_{1..10}`. To make sure your temp variables are unset so something like that doesn't happen: `unset _{1..10}`

Comment: Now THIS is exactly the kind of dirty hack that Just Works that I was looking for!

Answer (score 19):

This can be parameterized and doesn't require a temp variable, FWIW:

```
printf "%${N}s" | sed 's/ /blah/g'
```

Or, if `$N` is the size of a bash array:

```
echo ${ARR[@]/*/blah}
```

Comment: This is the shortest [POSIX 7](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html#tag_20_94) solution I have seen so far since `seq`, `yes` and `{1..5}` are not POSIX 7.

Comment: You shouldn't mix data into `printf`'s format specifier. What if the data contains format strings? This is the correct way to dynamically specify the "precision" (length): `printf '%*s'  "$N"` - make it a habit to enclose the format string in single quotes to prevent variable expansion there.

Answer (score 18):

Quite a few good ways already mentioned. Can't forget about good old `seq` though:

```
[john@awesome]$for i in `seq 5`; do echo "Hi";done
Hi
Hi
Hi
Hi
Hi
```

Comment: This one actually respects a zero, treating it as zero! (The `{i..j}` trick never returns an empty range.)

Answer (score 13):

Perhaps another way that is more general and useful for you:

```
adrian@Fourier:~$ n=5
adrian@Fourier:~$ for (( c=1; c<=n; c++)) ; do echo "HelloWorld" ; done
HelloWorld
HelloWorld
HelloWorld
HelloWorld
HelloWorld
adrian@Fourier:~$
```

The bash shell is more powerful than most people think :)

Comment: This gets my vote, as it's entirely shell-internal; no forking required.

Comment: What forking are you referring to? The original answer requires none. The output of 'type printf' is 'printf is a shell builtin' and therefore runs within the original bash process.

Comment: This is the only one so far (`yes`, `printf`, `for i in {1..5}`) that if the `n` is zero, it returns empty string without exist status of 1. Also due to the mathematical notation for comparison, it is easy to have offset by 1 (e.g  by changing the `<=` to `<`)

Answer (score 12):

Repeat `n` times, just put `n-1` commas between `{}`:

```
$ echo 'helloworld'{,,}
helloworld helloworld helloworld
```

Repeats 'helloworld' twice after the first echo.

Comment: Nice, but what if I want to get `n` from a variable?

Comment: it add an extra space after each 'helloworld'

Comment: this doesn't seem to let you put newlines in the string either (ie getting helloworld on their own lines)

Comment: @GetFree: most solutions here use bash's `{1..5}` expansion, which also does not support parametrize from a variable

Answer (score 12):

No magic here:

```
seq 5 | awk '{print "Hello World"}'
```

Comment: If whitespace between the lines is not desired, can change it to printf:
`seq 5 | awk '{printf "Hello World"}'`

Answer (score 8):

I've experienced broken pipe warnings with the `yes` solution, so here's another good alternative:

```
$ seq 4 | sed -E 's/.+/foo/'
foo
foo
foo
foo
```

Comment: I love this one. Thanks

Comment: These days I'd probably go with `sed -E 's/.+/foo/'` instead :) less arcane and more compatible; `sed -E` is historically supported by bsd and gnu, and is becoming posix

Comment: Doesn't work on macOS

Comment: @AdamStewart Indeed, bsd sed's `c` command works a bit differently; the solution was given in the previous command though. anyway, i've updated the answer

Answer (score 6):

POSIX AWK:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
function str_repeat(s1, n1) {
   s2 = ""
   for (n2 = 1; n2 <= n1; n2++) {
      s2 = s2 s1
   }
   return s2
}
BEGIN {
   s3 = str_repeat("Sun", 5)
   print s3
}
```

Or PHP:

```
<?php
$s3 = str_repeat('Sun', 5);
echo $s3, "\n";
```

Comment: Use this without the awk:  
while (( c++ < 5 )); do printf 'hello'; done

Comment: POSIXly portable. I like this answer

Answer (score 5):

based on what @pike was hinting at

for every character in string echo string

```
echo ${target//?/$replace}
```

An example of a heading underlined with `=` characters

```
export heading='ABCDEF'; 
export replace='='; 
echo -e "${heading}\n${heading//?/$replace}"
```

will output

```
ABCDEF
======
```

This seems to port between linux and OS X and that makes me happy.

nJoy!

Answer (score 4):

If you're on BSD, you can just use `seq`.

```
$ seq -f "Hello, world" 5
Hello, world
Hello, world
Hello, world
Hello, world
Hello, world
```

Comment: In `seq (GNU coreutils) 8.25`, this gives `seq: format 'Hello, world' has no % directive`, forcing a formatting directive to be present. GNU coreutils are used e.g. n many Linux distributions and Cygwin. Including the info here for those missing the info that it works only in BSD seq.

Comment: Doesn't work on macOS

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly built in to linux, but if you have python installed..

```
python
>>>var = "string"
>>>var*n
```

Or in one line, as commenter suggested:

```
python -c 'print "This is a test.\n" * 10'
```

Comment: Not really that useful, since it can't be easily integrated into shell scripts, etc. And since there's about a billion ways to do this in the shell itself, I see little reason to bring out the big guns (i.e Python) for it.

Comment: I agree with your second point but not the fist...it's easy to integrate into a shell script:   python -c 'print "This is a test.\n" * 10'

Comment: I like the readability of this solution, good reason enough for me. ;)

Comment: @AdrianPetrescu this is hardly different from the other solutions that are using things like `sed` and `awk` except that it's more readable. Unless you're running it in a tight loop many times, the cost of starting the interpreter is negligible.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want something like Perl's `x` operator, where you don't automatically get a newline between repetitions:

```sh
x() {
  # usage: x string num
  for i in $(seq 1 $2); do printf "%s" "$1"; done
  # print a newline only if the string does not end in a newline
  [[ "$1" == "${1%$'\n'}" ]] && echo ""
}

x Hi 10  # ==> HiHiHiHiHiHiHiHiHiHi

x $'Hello World!\n' 3
```

I explicitly used a `for` loop because you can't write `{1..$n}` in bash: brace expansion is done before variable substitution.

Answer (score 2):

```
line="==========================="
line=${line:0:10}
${line//"="/"ten "}
```

outputs

```
ten ten ten ten ten ten ten ten ten ten
```

Comment: Maybe a more verbose example: declare c='-----'; c=${c//${c:0:1}/$c}; echo $c # Prints "-" 25 times.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
echo $(for i in $(seq 1 100); do printf "-"; done)
```

Will create (a hundred dash):

---

Comment: I like this answer, as when "n" is an environment var (e.g. `$n`), the curly-brace syntax doesn't work: `n=10 && echo {1..$n}` produces `{1..10}`, whereas `echo {1..3}` produces `1 2 3`.

Answer (score 0):

On macOS and BSD you can use [`jot`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/1/jot/)

```
# Print 5 lines of `HelloWorld`
jot -b "HelloWorld" 5

# Print `HelloWorld` 5 times without newlines
jot -s "" -b "HelloWorld" 5

# Print `Hello` 5 times using a different separator which is `World` instead of newline
jot -s "World" -b "Hello" 5
```

On Linux you can install [athena-jot](https://www.unix.com/man-page/debian/1/athena-jot/) to get it

Like `yes`, this solution allows for **any number of repetition `$N`** and is **very fast** although not extremely fast like `yes` or [customized native solutions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/199528/13151) with [SIMD](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236630/13151) and [splice](https://mazzo.li/posts/fast-pipes.html) which can achieve *tens of GBs of data per second*

With `yes` you can print without new lines like this

```
$ N=10000000
$ WORD=HelloWorld
$ yes $WORD | tr -d '\n' | head -c $(($N * ${#WORD}))
```

---

### Benchmark:

Looping directly with the shell is slow for obvious reasons, therefore will be unsuitable for huge `$N` values. You'll always need some external tools like `yes`, `sed`, `tr`... for fast output. The brace expansion trick `{1..$N}` also completely fails when `$N` is large due to *argument list too long* error and using variable string replacement like in [commonpike's answer](https://superuser.com/a/174567/241386) will make the shell give up soon due to lack of memory or the OOM will kick in

Below is some results when printing the word following by a new line

```
$ time bash -c "echo $WORD\$_{1..$N} >/dev/null"

real    0m15.863s
user    0m15.189s
sys 0m0.646s

$ time bash -c "for i in {1..$N}; do echo $WORD; done >/dev/null"

real    0m42.728s
user    0m38.029s
sys 0m4.673s

$ time bash -c "for i in \$(seq $N); do echo $WORD; done >/dev/null"

real    0m43.073s
user    0m39.349s
sys 0m4.507s
```

As you can see they're very slow. External tools will blow them out

```
$ time bash -c "printf %${N}s | sed 's/ /$WORD\n/g' >/dev/null"

real    0m1.913s
user    0m1.847s
sys 0m0.071s

$ time jot -b $WORD $N >/dev/null

real    0m1.262s
user    0m1.255s
sys 0m0.005s

$ time yes $WORD | head -n $N >/dev/null

real    0m0.912s
user    0m0.903s
sys 0m0.031s

$ time gyes $WORD | head -n $N >/dev/null

real    0m0.930s
user    0m0.947s
sys 0m0.090s

$ time yes $WORD | ghead -n $N >/dev/null

real    0m0.246s
user    0m0.138s
sys 0m0.213s

$ time gyes $WORD | ghead -n $N >/dev/null

real    0m0.258s
user    0m0.175s
sys 0m0.242s
```

I'm doing these tests on macOS and in the last 4 tests you can see how terrible BSD tools are compared to GNU tools (prefixed with `g` due to name clashing with the default BSD tools), even though they're still far faster than the shell

The above cases are with a trailing new line, and when printing **without new lines** GNU tools also leave BSD tools in the dust

```
$ time yes $WORD | tr -d '\n' | ghead -c 300M >/dev/null

real    0m26.763s
user    0m26.857s
sys 0m0.381s

$ time gyes $WORD | tr -d '\n' | ghead -c 300M >/dev/null

real    0m27.972s
user    0m28.142s
sys 0m0.598s

$ time yes $WORD | gtr -d '\n' | ghead -c 300M >/dev/null

real    0m1.353s
user    0m0.609s
sys 0m0.981s

$ time gyes $WORD | gtr -d '\n' | ghead -c 300M >/dev/null

real    0m0.980s
user    0m0.785s
sys 0m1.095s
```